# Issue Installing java

Tags: java, installation

so i was installing java and my pc decided to shut off before it could finish, i don't have java anymore, and now when i try to open the installer it never opens, i have tried using CCleaner to clean the registry, i have tried installing in safe mode, someone told me to check the checksum to make sure the file isn't corrupted and its not, i have tried the offline and online installers with no luck

i have been trying to solve this for a week with no luck =P was hoping you guys could help

Comment: What version of Java were you trying install, and was this the JRE or the JDK?

Comment: While this is on topic here at SO, you may get better responses over at http://www.superuser.com

Comment: i was trying to install jre 8U91 the one available right from http://java.com/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

You could try deleting the location it was installing to and then reinstalling.